# Sequelize app.post : why "TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to make a post request, to post products that I test my route to Postman but it doesn't work.

On Postman I have just :

> {}

When I'm doing a console.log (req.body) I get the data back.

On my terminal I have this error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

**My route post request :**

`routes/Product/addProduct.js`  — this is where the error occurs.

```
const { Order } = require('../../models/Product/order');
const { Product } = require('../../models/Product/product');
const { ProductOrder } = require('../../models/Product/productOrder');

module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/orders/create', (async (req, res) => {

    try {
      // Create and save the order
      const savedOrder = await Order.create(req.body, { w: 1 }, { returning: true });

      // Loop through all the items in req.products
      req.body.products.forEach((item) => {

        // Search for the product with the givenId and make sure it exists. If it doesn't, respond with status 400.
        const product = Product.findById(item.id);
        if (!product) {
          return res.status(400);
        }

        // Create a dictionary with which to create the ProductOrder
        const po = {
          orderId: savedOrder.id,
          productId: item.id,
          qty: item.qty,
        }

        // Create and save a productOrder
        const savedProductOrder = ProductOrder.create(po, { w: 1 }, { returning: true });
      });

      // If everything goes well, respond with the order
      return res.status(200).json(savedOrder)
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error("Order creation server error: ", error);
      res.status(500).send(error)
    };
  }));
}
```

**My models :**

`models/Product/order.js`

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
    uuid: DataTypes.UUID,
    address: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  Order.associate = function(models) {
    Order.belongsToMany(models.Product, {
      through: 'ProductOrders',
      as: 'products',
      foreignKey: 'orderId',
      otherKey: 'productId'
    });
  };
  return Order;
};
```

`models/Product/product.js`

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
    uuid: DataTypes.UUID,
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.TEXT,
    price: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
  }, {});
  Product.associate = function(models) {
    Product.belongsToMany(models.Order, {
      through: 'ProductOrders',
      as: 'orders',
      foreignKey: 'productId',
      // otherKey: 'orderId'
    });
  };
  return Product;
};
```

`models/Product/productOrder.js`

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ProductOrder = sequelize.define('ProductOrder', {
    uuid: DataTypes.UUID,
    productId: DataTypes.UUID,
    orderId: DataTypes.UUID,
    quantity: DataTypes.DECIMAL
  }, {});
  ProductOrder.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return ProductOrder;
};
```

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work, but in my case I use this format for my imports: `const Order = require('../../models/Product/order').Order;`, with the same way of defining the models.

Comment: You are exporting functions but want to 1. destructure them 2. use them as if they are the objects they return. So, you don't need the `{ }` when importing and you likely need to *execute* whatever you import with the correct parameters to actually get those objects.

Comment: @YannickK 
I have already tried like that I always get the same error

Answer (score 2):

You are exporting functions and trying to de-structure into an Object. Try below code:

```
const  Order  = require('../../models/Product/order')(sequelize, DataTypes);
const  Product  = require('../../models/Product/product')(sequelize, DataTypes);
const  ProductOrder  = require('../../models/Product/productOrder')(sequelize, DataTypes);
```

Comment: `ReferenceError: sequelize is not defined or DataTypes is not defined`

but following your logic it should work as it recovers models

Comment: Thank you very much. I don`t now, but without this calling method, default sequelize models not working. It was surprise for me.